# how to hide parse config keys from client side rendering

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, parse-platform

My parse app has Parse.initialize... in some client side code for login and signup. Is there anyway to hide this when the app is rendered so that any random person can't inspect element and see it?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

You could [obfuscate](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) them, but you can't stop someone who is determined to get them.

You need to assume that your [applicationID and client ID are NOT secret](https://parse.com/docs/data#security). Any restrictions you need to make to client data should be done with ACL's, class permissions, and cloud code. Assume incoming connections are hostile.